# CloudFormation S3 specify physical name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, naming, bucket, aws-cloudformation

I deployed a template with an s3 bucket. I noticed that the 'Logical ID' field is the resource name, but the 'Physical ID' field is in the format of --. Is there a way to override this behavior? I need to be able to specify an EXACT name. Everywhere Ive looked suggests that I make it through the console, but that's useless to me. I need automation.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're looking for a way to create a unique identifier, you could add metadata to the template and access it with `DescribeStackResource`. I believe the physical name isn't something that can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to set a custom physical id for a few kinds of ressources. ELB is one of them. ATM (Dec/2014) this ressources support custom pysical ids:

- AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
- AWS::DynamoDB::Table
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
- AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
- AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
- AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
- AWS::RDS::DBInstance
- AWS::S3::Bucket
- AWS::SNS::Topic
- AWS::SQS::Queue

For more Infos see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html

To set a custom name for a S3-Bucket set the property `BucketName` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-name)

Answer (score 0):

I have been coming up against the same issue. I know it *is* possible to set the physical name of a resource when you create it using the Ruby SDK for AWS. We use this ability so we can tear down/create ELBs with known and stable physical names, based on the environment and server role, and the backend nodes can auto-join upon deployment by looking for the ELB corresponding to their own environment and role.

However, when using CloudFormation, certain resources (ELBs, SGs) take the resource name you specify and prefix or suffix it with things like the stackID etc. Which breaks the above system by having ELB names which are always different after each deployment.

The CloudFormation documentation is by no means bad, but it does seem to lack a lot of edge cases. I haven't yet found out if setting the physical name is possible or not.

The AWS SDK for Ruby is very easy to use - I have no prior experience of Ruby - but have found it straightforward to deploy/destroy resources, so you may find this an acceptable solution to your issue if you have not had any CloudFormation joy by now but, like me, require an automated route. In fact you can use the Ruby SDK to trigger the CloudFormation stack for the items whose names you can control, and then create the others fully under the Ruby SDK.